# How to assign an ID for each start_url in scrapy from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, scrapy

Lets say I have a dataframe as such:

```
 id     url
 1      www.google.com
 2      www.youtube.com
 3      www.google.com
 4      wwww.facebook.com
```

If I want to iterate each url in the dataframe. So what I'll do is:

```
start_urls = list(df['url'])

def parse(self,response):
    thing = response.css("*").extract()
    item = scrapyItem()
    item['content'] = thing
    yield item
```

and that'll iterate over my urls, and yield an item for each of them. The problem is that with the yielded file I have no way of telling different id apart.

The urls arent unique and I can't assign the URL as an "id", I need the "id" column from my dataframe combined with the URL to generate a unique id. How can i access the id column when iterating over my urls? Or alternatively what other approaches could I take to be able to achieve what I want?

EDIT: I have tried to save url as an "id" but that doesn't work due to the urls not being unique, scrapy also works asynchronously so the order of the items will not remain constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite duplicate urls, I could still use "response.url" as an ID despite duplicate records. Duplicate records would regardless return the same response and therefore I can go back to my dataframe and attach the same information to every place where I have that ID.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `iterrows`:

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row['url'])
    parsed_response = parse(response)
    df.loc[index, 'scrapy_content'] = parsed_response
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: I don't think that works with Scrapy. the start urls calls a default function for each item in the list, or something.